# Calculating Awk Output divide by mega=1048576

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

Hi Can someone please let me know how I can calculate the output field from this command to MB ?
The command below shows the 20 largest file in directory and sub directories
but I need to convert the output to MB. In my script I use an array.. But If you guys show me how to use awk to divide the output for this by mega=1048576
I would really appreciate it .. Please explain the options !!!

```
ls -1Rs | sed -e "s/^ *//" | grep "^[0-9]" | sort -nr | head -n20 | awk {'print $1'}
```

Thanks

Comment: `print $1 / 1048576`?  It would be more conventional to place the braces inside the single quotes: `awk '{ print $1 / 1048576 }'` though it does no actual harm as written in the question.  You might prefer to control the format a bit: `printf "%.3f\n", $1 / (1024 * 1024)`.

Comment: Can't you use ls' -h option? It stands for human readable and will make ls produce file sizes with appropriate units.

Comment: or `ls -l --block-size=MB` Although it rounds to nearest MB.

Comment: Hi Cannot use the -h option have various OS flavor   awk 'BEGIN{mega=1048576} $5 >= mega {$1 = $1/mega "MB"} {print}'  print $1  / 1048576 not working ..

Comment: You are supposed to replace `{ print $1 }` with `{ print $1 / 1048576 }`

Comment: Why not `du -h`? Parsing the output of `ls` looks quite fragile.

Comment: yes I did do that getting too many decimals -- not what I should see

Comment: 0.494217
0.494217
0.0278168
0.0213242
0.0183334
0.00486755
0.00400543
0.00283051
0.000823975
0.000823975
0.000823975
0.000823975
0.000823975
0.000823975
0.000823975
0.000823975
0.000823975
0.000823975
0.000823975
0.000823975

Comment: do not want to use DU

Comment: can somone help on how I can convert the output to MB

Comment: can't imagine where you got the idea that `awk {'print $1'}` was correct syntax instead of `awk '{print $1}'` but stop doing that now.

Answer (score 1):

You don't show any sample input or expected output so this is a guess but this MAY be what you want (assuming you cant follow all the other good advice about not parsing `ls` output and you don't have GNU awk for internal sorting):

```
ls -1Rs | awk '/^ *[0-9]/' | sort -nr | awk 'NR<21{print $1/1024}'
```

Note that you don't need all those other commands and pipes when you're already using awk.

Answer (score -2):

ls -1Rs | sed -e "s/^ *//" | grep "^[0-9]" | sort -nr | head -n20 | awk {'print $1 / 1024'}     To turn it into MB - You have to divide it by 1024